# ¿Es mejor usar @Transactional en la clase o en los métodos?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tengo una pequeña duda en cuanto a esto. Un amigo mío estaba teniendo problemas con su código, le estaba arrojando la excepción "nested transaction exception".

Cuando fui a ver su codigo noté que en su clase el declaraba dicha anotación sobre los métodos, cuando yo siempre lo había hecho sobre la clase toda mi vida (y fue así como me enseñaron en Spring)

No sé si esa excepción tenga que ver con este tema o que pero me surgió esa duda, ¿Cuál es la diferencia en declararlo en los métodos ? Tengo entendido que de esa forma, cada vez que se llame un método con esa anotación, una transacción nueva se crea, pero en cambio, cuando se coloca la anotación sobre la clase, cualquier método que se llame de dicha clase va a continuar con la transacción actual (no sé si sea correcto como lo entiendo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la mayoria de casos, las personas te responderan que depende de cual es tu objetivo. No es que una sea mejor que la otra, sino que una es diferente a la otra, y cada opcion se adaptara mejor al proposito que tengas.

En cuanto a las diferencias, propones 2 casos:

**Caso 1:**

```
@Transactional
public class MiClase {
   ...
}
```

**Caso 2:**

```
public class MiClase {
    @Transactional
    public void miMetodo(){
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

[Basandome un poco en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132822/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-transactional-on-class-vs-method), en el primer caso, cualquier interaccion con los metodos de la clase `MiClase` generara una transaccion, tal y como lo suponias en tu pregunta. Esta manera de usar la anotacion tiene la ventaja de ser un buen atajo para no tener que marcar todos los metodos dentro de una clase como transaccionales, **pero** si cuentas con metodos que en ningun momento interactuan con la base de datos, estaras iniciando transacciones innecesariamente.

Por otro lado, puede que no todos tus metodos que interactuen con la base de datos necesiten usar la misma estrategia. Cada metodo podria tener un diferente [nivel de isolacion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html), [propagacion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation--) o incluso [solo hacer rollback para ciertas excepciones en especifico](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor--). Por ello, utilizar el segundo caso te permitira tener mayor flexibilidad en tu codigo. **Ojo con este caso 2**, si un metodo no transaccional llama a un metodo transaccional dentro de la misma clase, **no se iniciara una transaccion**.

Es incluso posible anotar la clase y el metodo con la `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public class MiClase {
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void miMetodo1(){
        ...
    }

    public void miMetodo2(){
        ...
    }
}
```

En este caso `miMetodo2` sera transaccional al igual que `miMetodo1`, pero la configuracion de `miMetodo1` sobreescribira el comportamiento configurado por la anotacion de clase.

Yo recomendaria utilizar la anotacion de `@Transactional` individualmente en los metodos, para no crear involuntariamente transacciones para operaciones que no necesiten interactuar con la base de datos, y para poder configurar mas detalladamente como deberia interactuar la transaccion en cada uno de mis metodos. Ahora, si estas seguro que todos tus metodos necesitan de una transaccion y deben comportarse igual en todos los casos, colocaria la anotacion al iniciar la clase.